# LaTex table - increase column width

Tags: columns

I have a table - it looks densely packed. I would like to add width to the column 'test', 'p' and 'standardised beta'. Is there an easy way? Thanks.

(It's the first time I use LaTex, so apologies if this question is redundant and has an obvious answer. However, I couldn't find an easy way to do this.)

This is my table:

```
\begin{table} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Cognitive Domain}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{test}}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ p}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{standardized beta}}  \\ \hline
    Attention &  1956  & 0.00171 ** & -0.0712969  \\ \hline
    Crystalline Intelligence/Knowledge & 1783 & 0.02252 * & -0.06089968  \\ \hline
    Working Memory &  1817  & 0.0044 ** & -0.072473819  \\ \hline
    Learning &  1819  & 0.00475 ** & -0.075947316 \\ \hline
    Executive &  1964  & 0.1204 & -0.043642248 \\ \hline
    Fluency &  1828  & 0.14442 & -0.039730441  \\ \hline
    Visoconstruction &  1825  & 0.113054 & -0.044836878 \\ \hline
    Language &  1105  & 0.01200 * & -0.08003825 \\ \hline
    Social Cognition &  1441  & 0.875277 & -0.004813098 \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: You could always resort to ugly hacks like `~~~~test~~~~`.  But the spacing seems fine to me.

Comment: You could try with `p{width}` instead of `l`  as the alignment character to `tabular` environment, for example: `\begin{tabular}{ |l|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{3.5cm}| }`

Comment: Thanks Sunilkumar, that helps. If you think it warrants an answer perhaps you could make it an answer.